# Is it possible to save additional attribute value(that comes from two many-many relationship table) in laravel4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

Database Tables are

```
jobseekers                        
id | username | password |    

job_detail_jobseeker
id | jobseeker_id | job_detail_id | expected_salary

jobdetails
id | employer_id | cat_id | job_title
```

// Models

```
JobDetail.php // model

public function jobseekers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Jobseeker');
}


Jobseeker.php // model

public function jobdetails()
{
    return $this->bolongsToMany('JobDetail');
}
```

// Controller file

```
public function postSubmit()
{
    $input = Input::get('id');
    $jobdetail = JobDetail::find($input);
    $password = Input::get('password');
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $user = Jobseeker::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();
    if($user && (Hash::check($password, $user->password))){
    $user = Jobseeker::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->get();
    $salary = Input::get('salary');  // how to save in job_detail_jobseeker table
       foreach($user as $u)
       {
            $seeker = Jobseeker::find($u->id);
            $jobdetail->jobseekers()->save($seeker);
            // $jobdetail->save($salary);
            echo "success";
       }
    } 
    else {
        echo "not match";
    }

}
```

How to save "salary" in the job_detail_jobseeker table in by using laravel4.2. I am unable to save salary in the table. I am learning laravel, pls help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this along the lines of what you want? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Comment: my problem is solved, by using pivot table i have done my work... thanks for your response... @haakym